# Quicker way to filter lists based on a check to external variable?

Tags: python

I have a variable  = 'P13804'

I also have a list like this:

```
['1T9G\tA\t2.9\tP11310\t241279.81', '1T9G\tS\t2.9\tP38117\t241279.81', '1T9G\tD\t2.9\tP11310\t241279.81', '1T9G\tB\t2.9\tP11310\t241279.81', '1T9G\tR\t2.9\tP13804\t241279.81', '1T9G\tC\t2.9\tP11310\t241279.81']
```

You can see, if you split each item in this list up by tab, that the third item in each sub-list of this list is sometimes 'P11310' and sometimes is 'P13804'.

I want to remove the items from the list, where the third item does not match my variable of interest (i.e. in this case P13804).

I know a way to do this is:

```
var = 'P13804'
new_list = []
for each_item in list1:
     split_each_item = each_item.split('\t')
     if split_each_item[3] != var:
           new_list.append(each_item)

print(new_list)
```

In reality, the lists are really long, and i have a lot of variables to check. So I'm wondering does someone have a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Filtering is an `O(n)` operation - you will have to go through the whole list anyway. You can avoid splitting the elements of the list by just checking `if var in each_item` - but that does not guarantee that the __3rd__ part of the item is that var, it can be any part of the item

Comment: Great thanks, even just knowing I'm not missing something obvious is useful.

Comment: ^more on this, assuming each string is the same length, the way you can guarantee it's in the third part of the item, is by doing the same thing but slicing "each_item". So "if var in each_item[index_start:index_end]:

Answer (score 1):

It is generally more efficient in Python to build a list with a comprehension than repeatedly appending to it. So I would use:

```
var = 'P13804'
new_list = [i for i in list1 if i.split('\t')[2] == var]
```

According to timeit, it saves more or less 20% of the elapsed time.